# Minimal virtual machine Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server, ubuntu-minimal

I am installing Ubuntu Server 18.04, after the boot I press F4 but the only options I have are just:

- Normal
- Use driver update disc
- OEM install
- OEM install

I miss:

- Install a minimum system
- Install a minimal virtual machine

Instead if I use Ubuntu Server 16.04 I have these options.
How can I solve?

Comment: You weren't specific on which Ubuntu 18.04 ISO/media you installed with (eg. 18.04, 18.04.1, 18.04.2, 18.04.3, 18.04.4 or the standard/alternate installer you used). For older ISOs the 'di' installer was default, in the latest the 'di' is the alternate installer with `subiquity` now the default installer.  Specifying you which you used would be helpful as options vary on each (release + which installer).  Ubuntu 16.04 only used the 'di' installer.

Comment: Thanks, for helping I installed 18.04.4 from this link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/
Server install image

Comment: That link makes me think (it has a number of files available, but it stresses the 'live' image there being the 'new' default) that you used the new 'live' installer (`subiquity`) where as your 16.04 install would have been the 'di' (debian installer, text based & non-live system). The 'di' installer is now the alternate installer for 18.04.4  Sorry I haven't used the 'di' installer in awhile so can't confirm if it still has the options you want in 18.04.4 (but you are using a different installer to last time).

Comment: Mh so how can I solve my problem?